# EnumResTypeProc blank LPTSTR argument

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I have the following code to enumerate all the resource files in a given .exe

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumResNameProc(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpszType, LPTSTR lpszName, LONG_PTR lParam);
BOOL CALLBACK EnumResTypeProc(HMODULE hModule, LPTSTR lpType, LONG_PTR lParam);

REMOTECONTROL_API BOOL EnumResources(LPCWSTR file1, LPCWSTR file2)
{
    HMODULE hFile = LoadLibrary(file1);

    BOOL bSuccess = EnumResourceTypes(hFile, EnumResTypeProc, NULL);

    FreeLibrary(hFile);

    return bSuccess;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumResNameProc(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpszType, LPTSTR lpszName, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumResTypeProc(HMODULE hModule, LPTSTR lpType, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, lpType, L"Type", 0);
    return TRUE;
}
```

But when the `EnumResTypeProc` callback is called, the argument `lpType` is a blank string.

Why does this happens?

Comment: You should not need a cast on the callback function. If you declare the function the same as the type, it will compile.

Comment: Resource types can be integers or strings, like RT_CURSOR and "PNG".  Review the MAKEINTRESOURCE and IS_INTRESOURCE macros.  So you are passing an invalid string pointer to MessageBox, it knows how to avoid crashing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648041.aspx), it says:

> lpszType [in]
>   Type: LPTSTR
>
> The type of resource for which the type is being enumerated. **Alternately, rather than a pointer, this parameter can be MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID), where ID is the integer identifier of the given resource type.**
>   ...
>   **If IS_INTRESOURCE(lpszType) is TRUE, then lpszType specifies the integer identifier of the given resource type.** Otherwise, it is a pointer to a null-terminated string.

Also [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008.aspx#_win32_Creating_a_Resource_List) says:

> Note that the lpszType in EnumResTypeProc is **either a resource ID or a pointer to a string** (containing a resource ID or type name); lpszType and lpszName in EnumResNameProc and EnumResLangProc are similar.

That means your callback's `lpType` parameter is not always a pointer to a string, like you are assuming.  Sometimes it is a number that has been type-casted as a pointer instead.

Try this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumResTypeProc(HMODULE hModule, LPWSTR lpType, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    WCHAR szMsg[256];

    if (IS_INTRESOURCE(lpType))
        StringCchPrintfW(szMsg, 256, L"Type: %u", (USHORT)lpType);
    else
        StringCchPrintfW(szMsg, 256, L"Type: %s", lpType);

    MessageBoxW(NULL, szMsg, L"Type", 0);

    return TRUE;
}

REMOTECONTROL_API BOOL EnumResources(LPCWSTR file1, LPCWSTR file2)
{
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    HMODULE hFile = LoadLibraryExW(file1, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    if (hFile != NULL)
    {
        bSuccess = EnumResourceTypesW(hFile, EnumResTypeProc, NULL);
        FreeLibrary(hFile);
    }

    return bSuccess;
}
```

Comment: The asker should read the documentation, which already explains that.

Comment: Much improved now with some text and explanations and doc links